# Compile c++ code from source c++ file in windows using System() in Visual Studio

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio-2012, system

When I use Developer Command Prompt for VS2012 and type

```
cl myProgram.cpp
```

**It compiles successfully**, 
However, now I want to compile that same file from within my source code in *mySourceCode.cpp*

using

```
system("cl myProgram.c");
```

When I try I get the following error

**fatal error c1034: proccess.h: no include path set**

I was wondering if there was a way to fix this from within the source code without having to change any environment variables?

My Source code would look something like this:  **mySourceCode.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include ... 
int main()
{
  //set up code 
  ...

  system("cl myProgram.c");
}
```

The code I want to compile: **myProgram.cpp**

```
#include <proccess.h>
#include <windows.h> 
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
  //set up code 
  ...

  Sleep(10000);
}
```

Comment: This may be helpful. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fwkeyyhe.aspx

Comment: Thank you, this may be a good start. I could be wrong, but I suspect when I call system, VS2012 uses the command prompt instead of the Developer Command Prompt which has the environment variables set with the "\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 8\vc\bin\vcvars32.bat." Haven't figured out how to reconcile these though

Answer (score 1):

> When I use Developer Command Prompt for VS2012...It compiles successfully

This should be a hint for you. Look what "Command Prompt for VS2012" link is - `%comspec% /k ""C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\vcvarsall.bat"" amd64` i.e it launches `vcvarsall.bat` file. Now look what that `.bat` is doing - it uses parameter(s) and other `.bat` files to set bunch of environment variables needed to successfully perform compilation, such as include path, library path and others.

When you call `system` most of those environment variables are not set in the process created by `system()` call. If you want to perform compilation from your program you have many different ways to it. For example, create a `.bat` file that you will launch, or use [CreateProcess](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682425(v=vs.85).aspx) function to create a process with appropriate environment